# Using drawRect to draw tablecell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, drawrect

So, I watched some WWDC 2010 videos, and in one video the speaker pointed out that it could be a good option to draw the custom tablecells using drawRect instead of putting them in IB, because it would be good for performance. I have always put them in IB, so I'd like to ask how I actually do it, just by overriding the drawRect function of the tablecell? Also is it worth it to use drawRect instead of IB?

Thanks, if you have something to ask I will elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, so yes, if you want to create one that does custom drawing you should override `-drawRect:`. There might be some situations where this gives improved performance, but it's probably not significantly different in the usual case where you're recycling cells and all the cells are similar.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll just stick to normal methods then.

Comment: This is not right, there are many cases where using drawRect is better. Please check Twitter Engineering blog where they show how they draw their cells with drawrect to get a better performance (@SamuliLehtonen) [Twitter Engineering: Simple Strategies for Smooth Animation on the iPhone](http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/02/simple-strategies-for-smooth-animation.html)

Comment: @Lookez That's a great article full of good tips, but note the warning about premature optimization.